# Is there any interpretation method suitable for CNNs which do regression tasks?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, regression, algorithm-request, model-request, explainable-ai

I mainly tackle regression problems by CNNs, and want to find a reliable method to calculate the heatmaps for NN's results. However, I find almost all interpretation methods including CAM is used for classification NNs but not for regression NNs.

Is there any interpretation method suitable for CNNs which do regression tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct that GradCam does not support regression in its formulation, but most gradient-based saliency map methods do support regression, for example:

1. Guided Backpropagation
2. Integrated Gradients
3. SmoothGrad

Also in non-gradient methods, LIME supports regression as well.

Comment: Thanks for you answering! Whether these methods are also useful in relatively simple Fully connected neural network or is only  used for CNNs. And how can i choose a suitable one among them? Are there a document about limitations or comparison about these methods.